# Formula to Create a Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

## Question:

I am looking for a formula to create the series:

1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25,30,36,42,49,56,64,...

## Steps Tried:

I realized the above series is the sum of two series as shown below.

First  Series: 0,2,2,6,6,12,12,20,20,30,30,42,42,56,56,...

Second Series: 1,0,2,0,3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0,...

But I am not sure how to create the above two series.  But clearly there is a pattern. The first series is the product of consecutive natural numbers but with one repetition. The second is just natural numbers with zero in between them.

If there is a direct way to create the original series, that might be okay as well. Please let me know.

If this is a very simple question. It has not been simple for me. Hence, please provide steps and helpful suggestions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Usually such questions are ill-posed, but here we have a reasonable guess. The sequence apparently contains the perfect squares and the doubled triangle numbers.

Comment: @Peter, Thanks for your good suggestion. As you can see from the question, we can also write the original series as the sum of the two series. But I am unsure how to write a formula to get the next term of the original series or a formula to get the next term of the two series that sum to give the original series.

Comment: With $n$ starting at $1$ the second series is $\frac{1-(-1)^n}4 (n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Is this
$$a_n=\left\lfloor\frac{(n+1)^2}4\right\rfloor?$$

Comment: @user249613 What do you mean by "too quickly"? Your sequence are of quadratic growth, and so is the suggested formula.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, Could you please also suggest any series formula for the two series that sum to give the original series. I am just curious to know this better. Am happy to make this a new question, if necessary.

Comment: @user249613 It would be more enlightning if a description would be added how to arrive at this formula.

Comment: @Peter, Please note, I am not sure how the user who answered this question got this formula. You are right that might be interesting. I just noticed that the original series can be written as the sum of two other series.

Answer (score 1):

This is [OEIS sequence A002620](http://oeis.org/A002620) "Quarter-squares" which has several formulas for the sequence, including $a(n) := \,\textrm{floor}(n^2/4)\,$
for a suitable offset where $\, a(0)=a(1)=0,\,$
$\, a(2)=1.\,$

For your idea of using the sum of two other sequences, let $\, b(n) := \textrm{floor}((n-1)/2)\textrm{floor}((n+1)/2), $
$\, c(n) := (1+(-1)^n)n/2. \,$  Then $\, a(n) = b(n) + c(n). \,$

Comment: Your $b(n)$ does not grow quadratically as required.  I think you just need to square the expression, outside the floor.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. I forgot the 2nd factor.